# How to merge a JsValue to JsObject in flat level

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have two JsValue created from case class, i.e. Book and Book detail

```
val bookJson = Json.tojson(Book)
val bookDetailJson = Json.tojson(BookDetail)
```

and the format would be:

```
//Book
{
  id: 1,
  name: "A Brief History of Time"
}

//BookDetail
{
  bookId: 1,
  author: "Steven Hawking",
  publicationDate: 1988,
  pages: 256
}
```

How can I merge them to a single Json in play-framework 2.10? i.e.

```
//Book with detail
{
  id: 1,
  name: "A Brief History of Time",
  bookId: 1,
  author: "Steven Hawking",
  publicationDate: 1988,
  pages: 256
}
```

I was trying the transformation and failed to iterate through the second JsValue:

```
val mapDetail = (__).json.update(
                  __.read[JsObject].map { o =>
                  o.deepMerge( JsObject(Seq(("detail", bookDetailJson))) )
                })

bookJson.validate(mapDetail).get
```

It would become one level down, which I don't really want.

```
//Book with detail
{
  id: 1,
  name: "A Brief History of Time",
  detail: {
            bookId: 1,
            author: "Steven Hawking",
            publicationDate: 1988,
            pages: 256
          }
}
```

Please let me know if any trick could provide on this Json transform.  Many Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the `JsObject` class supports the `++` method for combining two `JsObject`s.  Have you tried casting them to `JsObject` (if they already are not that type) and then using `++`?

Comment: That was my frist attempt which gave me the same result. Indeed, I thought deepMerge would give me a better answer.

Comment: The real problem is when I converting a JsValue to JsObject, I can only use 
JsObject(Seq(("details", detailsJson)))
which would generate this:
detail: {
            bookId: 1,
            author: "Steven Hawking",
            publicationDate: 1988,
            pages: 256
          }

Comment: Again, if you cast both to `JsObject`, you should be able to copy the fields from one into the other like so: `val newObj = a.copy(fields = fields ++ b.fields)`.

Comment: Sorry for trivial question.  What's the best way to cast a JsValue to JsObject?

Comment: It's totally ugly, but `jvalue.asInstanceOf[JObject]` where `jvalue` is the `JValue` you want to convert

Comment: Thanks cmbaxter! Indeed, that work for :
 val detailObj = detailJson.asInstanceOf[JsObject]
val mapDetail = (__).json.update(
            __.read[JsObject].map { o =>
            o ++ detailObj
        })

Answer (score 18):

Play has a lot of new features for JSON right now. This would be a nice showcase for the `Format[A]` trait (see [Scala Json Inception](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJsonInception)) which you could include implicitly as I will show, or explicitly to the methods that require an implicit `Format[A]/Reads[A]/Writes[A]`.

Create a case class to represent your JSON objects,

```
case class Book(id: Int, name: String)
case class BookDetail(id: Int, author: String, publicationDate: Int, pages: Int)
```

Create companion objects that contain the implicit `Format[A]` so that `Format/Reads/Writes` will automatically be in scope when you need them.

```
object Book { 
  implicit val fmt: Format[Book] = Json.format[Book] 
}

object BookDetail { 
  implicit val fmt: Format[BookDetail] = Json.format[BookDetail] 
}
```

Now you could do something like this,

```
val bookJson = Json.toJson(Book(1, "A Brief History Of Time"))
val bookDetailJson = Json.toJson(BookDetail(1, "Steven Hawking", 1988, 256))
bookJson.as[JsObject].deepMerge(bookDetailJson.as[JsObject])
```

And you will have an object like this,

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "A Brief History Of Time",
  author: "Steven Hawking",
  publicationDate: 1988,
  pages: 256
}
```

I've tried this in the REPL but it does not work, in a Play application it does just fine though. Also in a production scenario we would likely use `asOpt[T]` in place of `as[T]`.

Here is an example of why `asOpt[T]` may be better suited, suppose instead of a valid JSON object for book you get,

```
val bookJson = Json.toJson("not a book")
```

You will end up with a

```
[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsobject,WrappedArray())))))]
```

But suppose instead you change your method to use `asOpt[T]`,

```
bookJson.asOpt[JsObject].getOrElse(Json.obj()).deepMerge(bookDetailJson.asOpt[JsObject].getOrElse(Json.obj()))
```

Now you will end up with at least a partial JSON object,

```
{
  id: 1,
  author: "Steven Hawking",
  publicationDate: 1988,
  pages: 256
}
```

So depending on how you would like to handle improperly formatted JSON you could choose either option.

Comment: +1 Thanks soo much deepMerge was exactly what I was looking for but the Scala api is so big that its easy to overlook!

Answer (score 2):

JsObject is subtype of JsValue.

JsValue can be simple converted to the JsObject using *as* or *asOpt* methods from JsValue.
Example:

```
val someJsValue = ....
val asObject:JsObject = someJsValue.as[JsObject]
val asObjectMaybe:Option[JsObject] = v.asOpt[JsObject]
```

In the **case of JsArray** you can not use above code. 
If you use play and parse JSON with array, then *Json.toJson(...)* produces JsValue which is JsArray actually. 
You need to convert JsArray as following:

```
val someJsValueButArray = ....
val asJsArray:JsArray = Json.toJson(someJsValueButArray).as[JsArray]
val asSeqOfJsObjects:Seq[JsObject] = asJsArray.value.map(_.as[JsObject])
```