# Merge nested json using play scala

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have two JSON object (with the same structure):

The first one is

```
json1 = {a: {b: [{c: "x" , d: val1}, {c: "y" , d: val2}]} }
```

and the second is

```
json2 = {a: {b: [{c: "x" , d: val3}, {c: "y" , d: val4}]} }
```

is there any way to merge these two object to have one object (if c value is same then sum d values):

```
result = {a: { b: [{c: "x", d: (val1+val3) } , {c: "y", d: (val2+val4) }] } }
```

if

```
   json2 = {a: {b: [{c: "y" , d: val3}, {c: "z" , d: val4}]} }
    result = {a: { b: [{c: "x" , d: val1} , {c: "y", d: (val2+val4+val3)},{c: "z" , d: val4}] } }
```

Is there any built in method to do this trick. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge a JsValue to JsObject in flat level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596809/how-to-merge-a-jsvalue-to-jsobject-in-flat-level)

Comment: Why are you handling JSON when you don't know the keys? What are you trying to do with it? I'd recommend not touching data if you don't know at least how it is structured.

Comment: Updated question. Please suggest @JamesWhiteley

Comment: @Rumoku Sorry to say but it's not duplicate of marked question, as schema for both json object is same, need to merge values. Tried with deep merge but it returns 2nd json

Comment: True! But you actually do not merge values, (for ex. `c` has value "x" in output the same as original). I think you have convert it to scala classes and implement code to "merge" or "sum" those classes somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your JSON structure, one way of doing this would be to turn them into case classes and compare them. Here's a way I found (which is by no means optimised):

```
//Going by your JSON structure of {"a": {"b": [{"c": String , "d": Int}]}}

import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

case class A(a: B)
object A{implicit val format: OFormat[A] = Json.format[A]}

case class B(b: Seq[C])
object B{implicit val format: OFormat[B] = Json.format[B]}

case class C(c: Option[String], d: Option[Int])
object C{implicit val format: OFormat[C] = Json.format[C]}

val json1 = Json.parse("""{"a": {"b": [{"c": "x" , "d": 1}, {"c": "y" , "d": 2}]}}""").as[A]
val json2 = Json.parse("""{"a": {"b": [{"c": "x" , "d": 3}, {"c": "y" , "d": 4}]}}""").as[A]

val cSeq: Seq[C] = {
  (json1.a.b zip json2.a.b) map {
  // List((C(Some(x),Some(1)),C(Some(x),Some(3))), (C(Some(y),Some(2)),C(Some(y),Some(4))))
    c =>
      val (c1, c2) = c
      // assign a value to each element of the pairs

      val BLANK_C = C(None, None)

      if (c1.c.get == c2.c.get) C(c1.c, Some(c1.d.get + c2.d.get)) else BLANK_C
      // if the "c" keys match, add the "d" keys. If not, return an empty C model
      // will need to handle if get fails (ie None instead of Some(whatever))
  }
}

val json3 = Json.toJson(A(B(cSeq)))

println(json3)
// {"a":{"b":[{"c":"x","d":4},{"c":"y","d":6}]}}
```

Currently, if the parts don't match then it returns an empty object. You didn't specify what you want to happen when they don't match so I'll leave that up to you to sort out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it really helps. Updated a question little bit i.e. elements must be added irrespective of there order in sequence. Is there any way to do it. New to scala, don't have much idea of it.